# Chrome Extension: calculate in miliseconds and click button after specific seconds

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, settimeout

Well i am practising on Chrome Extension , i'm newbie on this.

Here is my code.

> popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laser Script</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            h1 { font-size: 22px; }
            .powered {
                font-size: 14px;
                margin-top: 8px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Scheduled Click</h1>
        <div id="contentWrapper">
            <input type="text" id="duration" placeholder="Duration">
            <input type="text" id="attack_date"  placeholder="Day/Month/Year">
            <input type="text" id="attack_time" placeholder="00:00:00">
            <button id="schedule">Start Attack</button>
        </div>
        <div class="powered">Courtesy of <img src="justpark_logo.png" width="170px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> popup.js

```
function initialise () {
    // here im calculating the remind time in (mileseconds) that the button have to be pressed 
    var attack_timeInput = document.getElementById("attack_time");
    var attack_timeParts = attack_timeInput.value.split(":");
    var hours = parseInt(attack_timeParts[0],10);
    var minutes = parseInt(attack_timeParts[1],10);
    var seconds = parseInt(attack_timeParts[2],10);
    var mileseconds = parseInt(attack_timeParts[3],10);     
    var attack_DateInput = document.getElementById("attack_date");
    var attack_DateInputParts = attack_DateInput.value.split("/");
    var day = parseInt(attack_DateInputParts[0],10);
    var month = parseInt(attack_DateInputParts[1],10);
    var year = parseInt(attack_DateInputParts[2],10);   
    var durationInput = document.getElementById("duration");
    var durationParts = durationInput.value.split(":");
    var hours2 = parseInt(durationParts[0],10)*3600000;
    var minutes2 = parseInt(durationParts[1],10)*60000;
    var seconds2 = parseInt(durationParts[2],10)*1000;
    var duration_mile = hours2+minutes2+seconds2;       
    var now = new Date();
    var new_now = now.getTime();
    var full_attack_date = new Date(year, month-1, day, hours, minutes, seconds, mileseconds); 
    var new_full_attack_date = full_attack_date.getTime();  
    var delayInputValue = new_full_attack_date - new_now - duration_mile;

    function scheduleClick () {
        document.getElementById("contentWrapper").innerHTML = 'The attack will start in ' + delayInputValue + 'miliseconds';
        var codeString = 'var button = document.getElementById("troop_confirm_go"); setTimeout( function() { button.click(); },'  + delayInputValue + ' )';
        console.log(codeString);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'console.log(document.getElementById("The attack will start ' + delayInputValue + ' miliseconds"))' });
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: codeString});
    };

    scheduleButton = document.getElementById("schedule");
    scheduleButton.addEventListener('click', scheduleClick, true);
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialise, false);
```

So i have 3 inputs. I calculate the remind time until the button will be clicked. (it works)

But in this part

```
document.getElementById("contentWrapper").innerHTML = 'The attack will start in ' + delayInputValue + 'miliseconds';
```

it diplays

> The attack will start in NaN miliseconds.

**and the button is pressed instantly.**

I ckeched also this code:

```
var  p = 1 ; //it's outside the function as the var delayInputValue
document.getElementById("contentWrapper").innerHTML = 'The attack will start in ' + delayInputValue + 'seconds';
```

and it displays :

> The attack will start in 1 miliseconds.

So here is my question, why it can't read and work with the `var delayInputValue` but i can the `var p`?
Can i fix it somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

Got it - the `initialise()` function is called when your DOM content is finished loading. At that point, the user has not entered information into the text fields, so they show as null or undefined. When the code starts running with this data it produces data as NaN since the calculations don't work.
In order for the code to run properly, you need to place the code dealing with data from those fields inside the `scheduleClick()` function, like so:

```
function initialise () {

    function scheduleClick () {
        var attack_timeInput = document.getElementById("attack_time");
        var attack_timeParts = attack_timeInput.value.split(":");
        var hours = parseInt(attack_timeParts[0],10);
        var minutes = parseInt(attack_timeParts[1],10);
        var seconds = parseInt(attack_timeParts[2],10);
        //var mileseconds = parseInt(attack_timeParts[3],10);     
        var attack_DateInput = document.getElementById("attack_date");
        var attack_DateInputParts = attack_DateInput.value.split("/");
        var day = parseInt(attack_DateInputParts[0],10);
        var month = parseInt(attack_DateInputParts[1],10);
        var year = parseInt(attack_DateInputParts[2],10);   
        var durationInput = document.getElementById("duration");
        var durationParts = durationInput.value.split(":");
        var hours2 = parseInt(durationParts[0],10)*3600000;
        var minutes2 = parseInt(durationParts[1],10)*60000;
        var seconds2 = parseInt(durationParts[2],10)*1000;
        var duration_mile = hours2+minutes2+seconds2;       
        var now = new Date();
        var new_now = now.getTime();
        var full_attack_date = new Date(year, month-1, day, hours, minutes, seconds); 
        var new_full_attack_date = full_attack_date.getTime();  
        var delayInputValue = new_full_attack_date - new_now - duration_mile;
        

        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = 'The attack will start in ' + delayInputValue + 'miliseconds';
    };

    scheduleButton = document.getElementById("schedule");
    scheduleButton.addEventListener('click', scheduleClick, true);
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialise, false);
```

Note that I also removed the miliseconds variable as the inputs I was using included hours, minutes and seconds only. You should also add some code to sanitise inputs to make sure they are in the format you want before calling the function.

Hope that helps

Comment: You are right  , i changed it before upload it here , and i forgot to change it, my bad

Comment: What are you entering as the inputs?

Comment: i will give you examples. In duration ->1:00:00 , In attack_date-> 30/3/2021 , In attack_time  ->23:10:01:300 (the 300 are the miliseconds).

Comment: And it finds out the remind miliseconds until the attack have to start so it will arrive in the attack_time

Comment: Updated my answer having played about with your code for a bit. Works for me now, so I hpe my explanation made sense